# Where to check number of request made to google places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google places API and there is a daily limit. 
So can anywhere inside my developerr account i can check the how much request are available and how much are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, in Google developer console you can check usage for each API. Open dashboard, select a Places API and go to the Quota tab.

The direct link looks like

`https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places-backend.googleapis.com/quotas?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID`

You will see something similar to this screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you @xomena. That helps.